How to modify the DynamicRTSPServer class behavior of LIVE555 to re-stream an RTSP URL instead of a file path?
I want to use the LIVE555 to re-stream an RTSP URL. The problem with the current LIVE555 proxy server is that we have to initially set all the RTSPs that will be re-streamed but I don't have them in the first place. In my case when a user requests to play stream I will modify the class to generate a new RTSP stream and then I need to re-stream it.
I know I can generate a new instance of the RTSP server and start a new process but I do not know how to close this connection and dispose the RTSP server after the client breaks the connection.
As per my knowledge, the DynamicRTSPServer exactly does this thing but with files. It checks if a session for this file has been created or not dispose the connection and generate a new one.
In my case, RTSP URL will get modified with the start time and end time. Like this

rtsp://127.0.0.1/12:00:00_13:00:00
rtsp://127.0.0.1/13:00:00_14:00:00

These URLs are provided by the camera when we request it so I don't have a clear RTSP URL for which I can create an RTSP server initially. So I need a way to re-stream such URLs and after their work they get removed from the memory.
